# How import data from DB to SOLR in chunks using DIH?

Tags: mysql, solr, dih

I'm trying to use DIH to import data from MySQL to SOLR, my query is made of join and left outer joins like:

```
   select * from products    join merchants on merchants.id=products.merchant_id                             

    left outer join cats_products on products.id=cats_products.product_id

    join categories on cats_products.category_id=categories.id;
```

,when I use join everything is ok,but when I want to make use of left outer join it takes a long time,and after a long time it returns nothing and gets out of time, I found something about using **batchSize** but when I change the number for this parameter it makes no differences, so one of my question is that why it have no affect?**batchSize="30000"** for example.

then I came up to use **limit** in my query and use lots of entity in my dih config with differente limits like:

```
    <entity name="first" query="select * from table LIMIT 0, 5000">
 ....
 </entity>
 <entity name="second" query="select * from table LIMIT 5000, 10000">
 ...
</entity>
```

but I have a huge amount of data and I can't use it for my full import.
so I was wondering maybe there should be some other ways to try,I mean to fetch data from data base in chunks or ...
any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: With MySQL, using `batchSize="-1"` helps  (see http://mysolr.com/tips/dataimporthandler-runs-out-of-memory-on-large-table/)

Comment: @arun thanks a lot it works for me!;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `start` and `rows` parameters? I've only done this from the admin panel, but you might experiment from there and see if that works for you. Otherwise you'll probably want to hit a URL like this: `[host]:[port]/solr/dataimport?command=[command]&clean=[true|false]&commit=[true|false]&start=[start]&rows=[rows]`

You will need to keep track of record offsets yourself, though.

If you're using SolrJ, you could probably do something like

```
solrQuery.set("command", "full-import");
solrQuery.set("clean", "true");
solrQuery.set("commit", "true");
solrQuery.set("start", "0");
solrQuery.set("rows", "1000");
```